# Youtube Carousel in Flutter

Tags: flutter, youtube, carousel

i am new to flutter and trying to make a carousel which holds youtube videos. The requirement for the carousel is that its height should be 300 width - full width.

1. when the carousel is visible on page by scrolling down the current video should play automatically same with scrolling out of view.
2. when the video completes current video should stop then carousel to scroll to next page and the now current video should play.
3. when user manually swipes the caousel, video on that page should automatically play.
4. this carousel should work with the least memory leak.